# During a poll, what is the percentage of examinated ballots needed to be 99% sure about the winner?

Tags: probability, forecasting

It's a simple question but hard to explain. At the end of a (say, political) poll *n* candidates will receive their respective percentage of votes, according to ballots. At this point, all the ballots will have been examinated. Now, before this time, the percentage of each candidate's votes varies as the examination of the ballots goes on but obviously will tend to its final value when all the ballots have been examinated. My question is: how many ballots (in percentage) do I have to examine to be sure that the current percentage of candidate's votes will be the final percentage of candidate's votes with 99% of probability? (Or with any percentage of probability)

Comment: It would be extremely unusual (as in, likely has never occurred) to examine ballots perfectly randomly.  Thus, the best you can hope for are mathematical bounds based on making no assumptions that the unexamined ballots resemble the already examined ballots in any way.  Consequently, the only rigorous, general answer will be tantamount to "you can stop examining once you have determined a winner."

Comment: Of course you stop examining once you have determined the winner but from my experience the winner has always been the leading candidate, even when not even the 75% of ballots have been examinated. A while ago I heard that the 35% of ballots are roughly enough to be reasonably sure about who the winner will. If I didn't misunderstood ,I was courious to know under which assumptions this is true and why

Comment: It's true when you are sampling the ballots randomly.  Otherwise, it is very, very wrong.  The original motivation for the fight over the results of the US presidential election arose by a confusion over this (willfully or not): in some states, such as Pennsylvania, the votes in the later ballots were entirely different from the votes in the earlier ballots, leading to a dramatic change in the outcome as the last few percent of the ballots were counted.  Ignore such experiences at your peril.